# Java и Kotlin в одном android проекте

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Есть довольно большой Android проект, целиком написанный на Java. Сейчас мне очень интересен Kotlin, и я хотел бы продолжать проект на нём. Я знаю, что это возможно, что Kotlin, как Java при компиляции компилируется в байткод.

Однако, интересно, с какими "подводными камнями" можно при этом столкнуться. Например, увеличенное время компиляции, может быть повешение сложности поддержки проекта и т.д.

Comment: kotlin отлично интегрируется в java проект и подводных камней (по сравнению с другими языками) минимум. Вы можете заменять понемногу java-классы кодом kotlin (и даже в одном классе) и все будет работать, но нюансы взаимодействия есть, конечно. Рекомендуется почитать книгу "Kotlin в действии" Жемеров Исакова, там об этом говорится, так же официальная документация.  Время компиляции смешанного проекта конечно увеличтся, как и сложность поддержки на двух языках, это естественно, но ничего "непреодолимого"

Comment: в случае андроида переход на котлин максимально безболезненный, да и почти все ключевые библиотеки  повыпускали расширения под котлин, так что проблем не будет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Kotlin (Ко́тлин) — статически типизированный язык программирования,
>   работающий поверх JVM и разрабатываемый компанией JetBrains.
>
> В мае 2017 года на конференции Google I/O команда Android объявила об
>   официальной поддержке языка Kotlin для разработки Android-приложений.

Вы испытаете минимальный дискомфорт, а даже некое удовольствие переписывая проект, потому что ребята очень постарались и знали, что люди будут пробовать "переходить", и внедрили некоторые фишки в саму IDE.

В вашем случае это идеальный вариант, та компания на которой работает AndroidStudio, внедряет язык работающий поверх JVM, который может дергать или быть вызванным из самой Java и это видно до компиляции, из этого все и говорят о полной совместимости. У языков есть свои особенности, если вы их знаете у вас не будет проблем с интеграцией. Если вы все таки хотите использовать 2 языка, то система LLVM позволяет это сделать, от этого в теории увеличится время компиляции, других проблем не должно быть.

Конечно многое зависит от сложности проекта, как, сколько, когда вы добавляете внешние библиотеки, хотите ли вы оба языка использовать в 1 классе. Ну здесь скорей проблемы будут от ваших умений и знаний и на сколько вы хорошо знаете этот проект, чтоб не потерять зависимости или свойства инициализации и тд. Я переписывал небольшой проект (в продакшн) по требования заказчика, как раз почти сразу после анонса оф поддержки, были проблемы с инструментал тестированием под Espresso, с Dagger2, я плевался на Kotlin мол всё работало как так? В итоге обычная проблема multidex с параллельными ссылками, которые сейчас вроде как частично(полностью) решены изменением команд в расширениях скрипта Gradle, да,да именно те команды Impl и annotationProcessor и с языком это не было никак связано. Я доделал проект и он стал другим, не могу сказать что лучше или хуже просто другим. Я нейтрален к другим языкам, хоть постоянно использую их, мне нравится читаймость хорошо написанного куска Java в Android с DI, но мне и нравятся некоторые фишки Kotlin, но одно скажу точно, переводить проект полностью с 1 в другой это трата денег для заказчика. На данный момент, не вижу смысла, кроме как самообучения.

Comment: "та компания на которой работает AndroidStudio" - тут все правильно?

Comment: я так и не понял, надо переписывать весь проект или можно в классах на java использовать kotlin?

Comment: @TimurVI 
Kotlin был создан и поддерживается компанией JetBrains, которая также разработала Android Studio. Как и Java, Kotlin работает поверх Java Virtual Machine (JVM). Это означает, что код Kotlin компилируется в байт-код JVM, который затем исполняется JVM, так же, как это происходит с кодом Java.

Comment: @Alex455 в 1 файле нет, разделить по файлам да, использовать 1 в другом в обе стороны - это и есть полная совместимость о которой говорится выше