# Как начать использовать kotlin у себя в проекте на java android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

У меня есть проект на java. Он довольно большой и поступило предложение попробовать kotlin. Я как-бы не против но погуглив и посмотрев пару уроков понял что пересесть с Java будет не так уже и просто. Вот к примеру [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766357/java-%D0%B8-kotlin-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-android-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5) там сказано что котлин и джава уживаются нормально в одном проекте и можно писать на том и на другом одновременно. Но я как-то не очень в этом уверен. Возможно проблема из-за того что я почти не знаю котлин и мне сложно его понять с первого раза, но мне интересно в нем разобраться. Чем мне не нравится kotlin - очень мало нормального ресурса в котором расписано что и как делается. Вот к примеру, есть у меня диалог на java:

```
public class PrivacyPolicyScreen extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static String TAG = "PrivacyPolicy";
    String text;
    TextView textPolicy;
    Button ok, cancel;
    SharedPreferences sp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            text = bundle.getString("policy_text");
        }

        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullScreenDialogStyle);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.privacy_policy_screen, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ok = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
        textPolicy = view.findViewById(R.id.tvPolicy);
        cancel = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);


        sp = Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0);


        if (!sp.getBoolean("read_policy", true)) {
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (sp.getBoolean("read_policy", true)) {
            ok.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            cancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.close_icon);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(this);
        toolbar.setTitle("Privacy policy");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));


        ok.setOnClickListener(view12 -> {
            sp.edit().putBoolean("read_policy", true).apply();
            Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), Home.class));
        });

        cancel = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(view1 -> System.exit(0));


        textPolicy.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(text, 0));
        textPolicy.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(getFragmentManager()).beginTransaction().remove(PrivacyPolicyScreen.this).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

Это довольно маленький класс и я решил его переделать на котлин. В студии есть возможность конвертировать классы java в kotlin но не буду же я сначала писать на java а потом переделывать в котлин. На мой взгляд это делать глупо. Начал я делать такой же класс с 0:

```
class PrivacyPolicyTest : DialogFragment()  {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_privacy_policy_test,container,false)
        MySingleton.getInstance().getPrivacyPolicy()
        return myview
    }

}
```

на этом мои потуги завершились, и это уже не говоря о том чтобы вызвать этот фрагмент с данными после запроса ретрофита на получение данных:

```
PrivacyPolicyScreen privacyPolicyScreen = new PrivacyPolicyScreen();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("policy_text", Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getPolicy_text());
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
privacyPolicyScreen.setArguments(bundle);
privacyPolicyScreen.show(ft, PrivacyPolicyScreen.TAG);
```

короче разбираться нужно с каждым аспектом этого языка, а нормального ресурса я не нашел. Получается что нужно все что раньше делалось на java делать на kotlin. Что вы мне посоветуете в сложившейся ситуации?

Comment: А вы не пробовали переконвертировать класс из java в kotlin, и посмотреть, как реализуется то, что у вас не получалось?

Comment: не пробовал если честно, думал что написав с 0 такой я смогу лучше узнать нюансы и тонкости.

Comment: @AntonSorokin, я пытался перед написанием этого вопроса конвертировать в kotlin, но у меня там были ошибки решить которые я не смог :(

Comment: Начать надо с изучения языка (как минимум синтаксиса и основ). Иначе как Вы будете его использовать, вслепую? Вот на первом же шаге уже и споткнулся...

Comment: @woesss, а какой ресурс вы посоветуете или просто гуглить и смотреть видеотуториалы по этому вопросу?

Comment: Начните с https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html Потом можно посмотреть разные видяшки на youtybe. И конечно нужно писать код. Раз у вас есть проект, берете класс и переписываете на kotlin, не нужно сразу пытать переписать сложную логику

Comment: рекомендую для начала полистать книгу Жемеров Исакова "kotlin в действии", есть русский вариант и там довольно сносно объясняются основы языка и идиомы, они довольно существенно отличаются от java, потом уже писать свой код

Comment: так же есть книга на английском от Antonio Leiva "kotlin for android developers" - уже конкретно в применении к Android, так же у него есть сайт. Кроме того на офф. сайте developers.android.com теперь примеры в документации дублируются на kotlin

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо большое за помощь буду пытаться переползти постепенно с java на kotlin :)